# JavaFX TableView integer not displaying

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i'm having problems with a tableview in JavaFX.

For some reason my TableView it's not displaying the Inventory column which is an integer, i've run some test & the reason it's because the getInventory function it's not being executed.

> Java Code

```
//Main Class
public class Main extends Application{
Stage window;
Scene scene1,scene2;
VBox panel;
TableView<Resources> table; 

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    //Stage
    window = stage;     
    window.setTitle("Test Application - TableView");

    //TableColumns
    TableColumn<Resources, String> name_c = new TableColumn<Resources, String>("Resource Name");    
    name_c.setMinWidth(200);
    name_c.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
    //---------------------------------------------

    TableColumn<Resources, Double> price_c = new TableColumn<Resources, Double>("Resource Price");  
    price_c.setMinWidth(125);
    price_c.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
    //---------------------------------------------

    TableColumn<Resources, Integer> inventory_c = new TableColumn<Resources, Integer>("Resource Inventory");    
    inventory_c.setMinWidth(125);
    inventory_c.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Resources, Integer>("Inventory"));

    //TableView
    table = new TableView<>();
    table.getColumns().addAll(name_c, price_c, inventory_c);
    table.setItems(getResources());

    //VBox
    panel = new VBox();
    panel.getChildren().add(table);

    // Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(panel,500,250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

public ObservableList<Resources> getResources(){
    //Inserts into the TableView the Values
    ObservableList<Resources> res = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    res.add( new Resources("Wood", 9.99, 100));
    res.add( new Resources("Iron", 12.85, 70));
    res.add( new Resources("Cotton", 3.16, 200));
    res.add( new Resources("Marble", 20.75, 50));
    res.add( new Resources("Glass", 5.99, 175));

    return res;
}
}

//Resources Class
public class Resources {

private String name;
private double price;
private int inventory;

//Constructors
public Resources(){
    this.name = "";
    this.price = 0;
    this.inventory = 0;
}

public Resources(String n,double p,int i){
    this.name = n;
    this.price = p;
    this.inventory = i;
}

//Getters & Setters.
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String nm) {
    this.name = nm;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double pr) {
    this.price = pr;
}

public int getInvetory() {
    System.out.println(inventory);//Inventory Test (Data not displaying, works with the other get functions)
    return inventory;
}

public void setInvetory(int inv) {
    this.inventory = inv;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be because you have `getInvetory()` method rather than `getInventory()`.

From the documentation of [PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through support for attempting to call `get<property>()` or `is<property>()` (that is, getFirstName() or isFirstName() in the example above).

And, you don't have the matching pattern which is either `getInventory()` or `inventoryProperty()`.

Comment: Thanks alot, it's working now. It's always the dumbest error the one i can't solve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am glad that this helped you. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.